# How to rotate the structuring element when using top-hat transform?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am implementing top-hat transformation on an image, the structuring element is 21 pixels long 1 pixel wide, how can I rotate this structuring element? So I can extract information in different angles from that image.

What I have now is

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
element = np.ones((21, 1))

new_image = cv2.morphologyEx(origin_image, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, element, iterations = 1)
```

But how to apply this to different angles? Like rotate the structuring element 30 degrees.

Comment: The structuring elements are just numpy arrays (images). So you can just rotate them with cv2.rotate(). However, they will need to be made larger in size with a zero (black) background accordingly. See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/ for code to do that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I constructed a numpy array filling with zeros, and fill the middle row as [1,1,1....,1], but it seems that this structuring element cannot be applied to top-hat transformation?

Comment: I got an error below:
OpenCV(3.4.2) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/morph.cpp:787: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _kernel.type() == 0 in function 'MorphFilter'
@fmw42

Comment: Untested: Do not pad the initial horizontal image with zeros. Just make a 1D array of 1s. Then use the link I gave to rotate it, but when rotating fill with zeros as the background color. I do not make any claim that such a rotated image will be accepted by morphology. What was your morphology command? The other way to approach it is to keep the structuring element as 1D ones, but rotate the image before applying, then rotate back after applying.

Comment: Which worked? Rotating the structuring element or the image? Perhaps you can post your solution as an addition to your original post or as a separate answer.

Comment: I just followed your idea, to fill all the zeros with some other numbers(like 10), then the error was gone, thanks

Comment: That was not really what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The function I used to rotate the structuring element is below:

```py
import cv2 
import numpy
def rotate_bound(image,angle):
    (h,w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cx,cy) = (w/2,h/2)

    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cx,cy),-angle,1.0)
    print(M.shape)
    print(M)

    cos = np.abs(M[0,0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0,1])

    nW = int((h*sin)+(w*cos))
    nH = int((h*cos)+(w*sin))

    M[0,2] += (nW/2) - cx
    M[1,2] += (nH/2) - cy

    return cv2.warpAffine(image,M,(nW,nH))

element = np.ones((21,1))
rotated_element = rotate_bound(element, 30)
rotated_element[rotated_element == 0] = 10
result = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, rotated_element)
```

Thanks for help from @fmw42 :)